# Can I use lifecycle hooks in Angular Guards?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, angular-router

I am working on angular. In my project the action for loading data on first page load is dispatched from a guard. I needed to modify the guard to access the store. I subscribe to the store in the constructor and access whatever data I want. Where can I unsubscribe from the store? Can I use ngOnDestroy??

This is my code

```js
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Store, Action, State } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import * as UpdateStore from '../store';
import { SetEntityType, LoadEntityList1 } from '../store/actions/Update.actions';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class EntityListingGuard implements CanActivate {
  Framework: any;
  Status: any;
  Type: any;
  destroyStore$ = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private store: Store<UpdateStore.State>,
    private actions$: Actions,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.store.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroyStore$)
    ).subscribe((state) => {
      this.Framework = state.SelectedFilters['frameworksChecked'] ? state.SelectedFilters['frameworksChecked'] : [];
      this.Type = state.SelectedFilters['typeChecked'] ? state.SelectedFilters['typeChecked'] : [];
      this.Status = state.SelectedFilters['statusChecked'] ? state.SelectedFilters['statusChecked'] : [];
    });
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const entityType = route.params['entityType'];
    const releaseId = route.params['releaseId'];
    const noOfUpdates = route.params['noOfUpdates'];

    const payload = {
      'searchTerm': '', pageLimit: 50, 'entityType': entityType, 'releaseId': releaseId, noOfUpdates: noOfUpdates,
      'checkedJobFrameworks': this.Framework 'checkedJobStatus': this.Type 'checkedJobType': this.Type  
    };

    this.store.dispatch(SetEntityType({ entityType: entityType }));
    this.store.dispatch(LoadEntityList1({ payload: payload }));

    const responseOK = this.actions$.pipe(ofType(UpdateActions.LoadEntityList1Success));
    const responseERROR = this.actions$.pipe(ofType(UpdateActions.globalError));
    return Observable.race(responseOK, responseERROR).take(1)
      .map(action => {
        if (action['type'] === '[Layout] Global Error') {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }).first();
  }
}
```

Comment: more "also", you are doing `take(1)` with `first`, using `actions` to look onto response, using *any*, naming convention, not using `router` - please, take a look on angular documentation more precisely, together with rxjs/ngrx

Comment: Edited the code to take care of `reducer`. Actually this is a kind of a dummy code, in that all the names are changed, it just resembles the original code, since I can't put the exact code on here. Plus it is someone else's code so I am even more confused.

Comment: got you, just pointing out parts that could cause problems and not stable from my perspective, and could do side-effect to main problem

Comment: although, main question could be found on google by simple "angular guard hooks" and you would get an answer right away about "guards are not components and etc."

Comment: Hmm. I discussed this with a team-mate but they were not clear about what problems the hooks could cause in guards. So we just moved that one action to the component's `ngOnInit` for now

Comment: 1. guards don't have hooks. 2. problem could be caused by the not correct usage of NgRx - it is not how Flux/Redux/Unidirectional data flow/State management should be constructed and used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guards are not components, so they don't have hooks. A way to do it would be taking data and unsubscribing immediately as you did for `race` with `take(1)`.

Also, looking at your code there is a mixup of logic with using the reducer after taking state. Reducers designed to *reduce* data into *store*. Please, consider taking a deep look at Flux/Redux pattern.

Second "also", the store is async and your guard could unpredictable - consider taking what you need inside `canActive` and return the result as observable.